# Improper Integral Convergence Properties

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Let $f,g:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous function with $f,g>0$ on $(0,\infty)$.

a) If $\int_1^{\infty}f(x) dx$ converges, then $\int_0^{1}\frac{1}{f(x)} dx$ converges.

b) If $\int_1^{\infty}f(x) dx$ converges and $\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=L>0$, then $\int_1^{\infty}f(x)g(x) dx$ converges.

Are these two statements true? I'm not sure where to begin to prove them or how to think of counterexamples. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: I found counterexample for a) f(x)=ln(x)/x^2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am gonna answer the question b)

Suppose $\int_1^{+\infty}{f(x)dx} = K$.

Since $f, g > 0$, we have that the function $\int_1^t{f(x)g(x)dx}$ is strictly increasing. Then $\int_1^t{f(x)g(x)dx} < K$.

From the fact that $g(x) \to L > 0$ when $x\to +\infty$ and the definition of infinite limit we have that
$$\forall ε > 0, \exists M>0:\forall x>M \implies |g(x) - L|< ε$$
Take $ε_0$ such that $L - ε_0 > 0$(you can always find one since $L>0$), so there exists $M_0$ such that $\forall x>M_0$ we have
$$0<L - ε_0<g(x)<L+ε_0 \implies$$
$$0<g(x)<L+ε_0 \implies $$
$$0<f(x)g(x)<f(x)(L+ε_0)\implies$$
$$0<\int_{M_0}^t{f(x)g(x)dx}<(L+ε_0)\int_{M_0}^t{f(x)}dx<(L+ε_0)K\implies$$
$$\int_{M_0}^t{f(x)g(x)dx}<(L+ε_0)K \implies$$
$$\int_{1}^{M_0}{f(x)g(x)dx}+\int_{M_0}^t{f(x)g(x)dx}<\int_{1}^{M_0}{f(x)g(x)dx}+(L+ε_0)K\implies$$
$$\int_{1}^{t}{f(x)g(x)dx}<\int_{1}^{M_0}{f(x)g(x)dx}+(L+ε_0)K$$

where $\int_{1}^{M_0}{f(x)g(x)dx}$ is constant. So $\int_1^t{f(x)g(x)dx}$ is strictly increasing and bounded, the limit when $t \to +\infty$ exists. So the integral $\int_1^{+\infty}{f(x)g(x)dx}$ converges.